# Iteratively concatenate columns in pandas with NaN values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `pandas.DataFrame` data frame:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"x": ["hello there you can go home now", "why should she care", "please sort me appropriately"], 
    "y": [np.nan, "finally we were able to go home", "but what about meeeeeeeeeee"],
    "z": ["", "alright we are going home now", "ok fine shut up already"]})

cols = ["x", "y", "z"]
```

I want to iteratively concatenate these columns, as opposed to writing something like:

```
df["concat"] = df["x"].str.cat(df["y"], sep = " ").str.cat(df["z"], sep = " ")
```

I know that three columns seems trivial to put together, but I actually have 30. so, I would like to do something like:

```
df["concat"] = df[cols[0]]
for i in range(1, len(cols)):
    df["concat"] = df["concat"].str.cat(df[cols[i]], sep = " ")
```

Right now, the initial `df["concat"] = df[cols[0]]` line works fine, but the `NaN` value in location `df.loc[1, "y"]` messes up the concatenation. Ultimately, the entire `1`st row ends up as `NaN` in `df["concat"]` due to this one null value. How can I get around this? Is there some option with `pd.Series.str.cat` I need to specify?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Option 1***

```
pd.Series(df.fillna('').values.tolist()).str.join(' ')

0                    hello there you can go home now  
1    why should she care finally we were able to go...
2    please sort me appropriately but what about me...
dtype: object
```

***Option 2***

```
df.fillna('').add(' ').sum(1).str.strip()

0                      hello there you can go home now
1    why should she care finally we were able to go...
2    please sort me appropriately but what about me...
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

**Option 3**

```
In [3061]: df.apply(lambda x: x.str.cat(sep=''), axis=1)
Out[3061]:
0                      hello there you can go home now
1    why should she carefinally we were able to go ...
2    please sort me appropriatelybut what about mee...
dtype: object
```