# Concatenate multiple pandas columns with carriage return and blank rows

Tags: python, string, pandas

I am attempting to concatenate multiple columns, all strings, in a pandas DataFrame; forming a new column. I am using .str.cat so that I can include a carriage return between columns to concatenate.

However, if any column in a row is blank or NaN I get NaN as the full result for that row.

I have looked at options and the third answer of this looks interesting:
[pandas combine two strings ignore nan values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33158417/pandas-combine-two-strings-ignore-nan-values)

However I cannot see a way to extend this to > 2 columns but still not all columns of the DataFrame, which is required.

The first two answers do not allow for addition of a carriage return, which is also required.

Here is my code:

```
mydf['Address'] = mydf['full name'].str.cat(mydf['Delivery address 1'], sep ='\n').str.cat(mydf['Delivery address 2'], sep ='\n').str.cat(mydf['Delivery city'], sep ='\n').str.cat(mydf['Delivery state'], sep ='\n').str.cat(mydf['Delivery postcode'], sep ='\n')
```

Which results in blank *mydf['Address']* for any row where any of the fields is blank.

What is the error in my code or my approach?

Comment: Create some toy data for us to experiment with and show us what you expect the results to look like

Comment: Related answer: [Iteratively concatenate columns in pandas with NaN values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39277838/iteratively-concatenate-columns-in-pandas-with-nan-values)... shout out to @piRSquared :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) with `axis=1` for process by rows with [`dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dropna.html) for remove `NaN`s:

```
#columns for join
cols = ['full name','Delivery address 1','Delivery address 2',
        'Delivery city','Delivery state','Delivery postcode']

mydf['Address'] = mydf[cols].apply(lambda x: '\n'.join(x.dropna()), axis=1)
```

If some columns is numeric:

```
mydf['Address'] = mydf[cols].apply(lambda x: '\n'.join(x.dropna().astype(str)), axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely not the most efficient way of doing what you asked, but you could always loop through the rows of the database and join all the strings together. Here's some psuedo-code

```
for row in your_database:
    your_database[new_column] = "\n".join([list of columns you want])
```